# f3 framework: unexpected behaviour of Cursor Method `load`

Tags: orm, fat-free-framework

I use the `load` method in a **loop** to execute a set of queries, each one like this one:

```
$events->load( "`user_id` = {$users->id} AND `action` = \"view\"");
```

where `$events` is the **mapper** and each loaded record represent an "event" (of course) in a log table.

After the `load` call I then iterate over the found records:

```
while( ! $events->dry() )
{
    // do something with $event

    $events->next();
}
```

When the (inner) `while` loop terminates another main loop iteration is executed, so `load` is called again.

This code do not produce the expected behaviour as some **events** apparently are not loaded.

I can fix it by placing either `$events->reset()` or `$events->first()` just before the `$events->load` statement.

However from the [documentation](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/cursor#load)

> ### load
>
> ---
>
> **Map to first record that matches criteria**
>
> [...] It uses find() to load records and makes the first record (mapper object) that matches criteria the active record. Additional records that match the same criteria can be made the active record by moving the cursor pointer

Now **the question is**: is this a **bug** of **f3** or I'm missing something ?

And as both `reset()` and `first()` (apperently) fix the problem, which one is more appropriate?

Comment: The syntax of your loop is correct. You don't need to call `reset`, unless you're updating/inserting events. In that case, you'd better use the `find()` method. See this [related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22344381/2588746) answer.

Comment: so I assume that `load` does not re-position the cursor to the first mapped record...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue on an older version of **F3** (3.4).

Updating to **3.6** solved the problem.

Comment: are you sure that this is the solution? as far as I can see, mapper->load calls reset internally, which should move the cursor pointer back to 0. maybe update your f3 core if you're using an older version?!

Comment: @ikkez I am VERY DUMB ! - I was still on 3.4. Updated to 3.6 and checked `load`, you're right `reset` is called before performing find. So there was an issue but has been fixed time ago.