# fatfreeframework PHP Database load and print

Tags: php, html, fat-free-framework

```
  public function profil(\Base $app)
{
    $hlasy = new data\Hlasy();
    $tit = new data\Titul();

    $tit->load(array('child=?',$app->get('SESSION.user[uuid]')));
    $app->set('stathrace',array($tit->parent));
    $hlasy->load(array('uuid=?', $app->get('SESSION.user[uuid]')));
    $app->set('stathrace', $hlasy->AllTimeTotal);






    echo \Template::instance()->render('profil.html');
}

                  <this is HTML>
   <repeat group="{{ @stathrace}}" value="{{ @stat }}">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ @stat.parent }} </td>
                    <td>{{ @stat.AllTimeTotal }} </td>
                    <td> X</td>
                    <td> X</td>
                    <td> X</td>
                    <td> X</td>
                </tr>

            </repeat>
```

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
I don't know how to fix it
I need find uuid ('SESSION.user[uuid]') its player id.. and use it to load in database and take data like parent (e.g. money) and next database ($hlasy) and again load that uuid and take allvotes from the player

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve, but 1) you're setting the variable `stathrace` twice 2) the error you get means that `stathrace` doesn't contain an array although your template expects one.

Comment: i need create contain and get data from databases hlasy and tit and print it.

Comment: i created contain and i have in stathrace 2 fields [],[] first is 0 and second 1
and I don't know how to print it in repeat group

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22344381/2588746) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`

public function profil(\Base $app)

```
    $penize = new data\Penize();
    $hlasy = new data\Hlasy();
    $tit = new data\Titul();

    $tit->load(array('child=?',$app->get('SESSION.user[uuid]')));
    $hlasy->load(array('uuid=?', $app->get('SESSION.user[uuid]')));
    $app->set('stathrace',array(($tit->parent),($hlasy->AllTimeTotal)));






    echo \Template::instance()->render('profil.html');
}




         <repeat group="{{ @stathrace}}" value="{{ @stat }}">
    <td style="width:20%;color:deepskyblue; text-align:center";>{{@stat }} </td>
                        </repeat>
```